# Maximum Laptop CPU temperature?

Tags: gaming, cpu-temperature

I have an HP 15 -ay016nv with i5-6200U and while gaming the maximum CPU temperature is 69 Celsius , measured with RealTemp , and when CPU is idle the CPU temperature is 25-30 Celsius.

Are these temperatures, 67-69 Celsius dangerous for my laptop ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Are these temperatures, 67-69 Celsius dangerous for my laptop?

No. The maximum temperature for your CPU is 100 Celsius:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Source [Intel® Core™ i5-6200U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/88193/Intel-Core-i5-6200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz)